# Creating Dynamic Ids - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to clone a chunk of form element HTML and add it to the DOM. The adding and deleting is working fine, but the newly-added input elements in the chunks are not getting unique ids and names.

I am not able to create unique attribute values for "name" or "id".

For some reason my selector `$('#myForm div:last').find('input').each(function(){...}`

is not catching these.

[Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/castonzo/pdHCc/1/)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var uniqueId = 1;
$(function() {
     $('.hyperlink').click(function() {

         var copy = $("#cosponsorsTemplate").clone(true).appendTo("#addCosponsorSection");
         var cosponsorDivId = 'cosponsors_' + uniqueId;
         copy.attr('id', cosponsorDivId );


         var deleteLink = $('<span class="t_formColumn5"><a class=\"icon delete\"></a></span><div class="clear"></div>');
         deleteLink.appendTo(copy);
         deleteLink.click(function(){
             copy.remove();
         });

         $('#myForm div:last').find('input').each(function(){
            $(this).attr('id', $(this).attr('id') + '_'+ uniqueId); 
            $(this).attr('name', $(this).attr('name') + '_'+ uniqueId); 



         });

         uniqueId++;  
     });
});
</script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container">
    <h2>Sponsors Section</h2>
    <form action="" id="myForm">
     <div id="addCosponsorSection" style="width:900px; margin-left:12px;">
        <div id="cosponsors">
            <span class="t_formColumn1"><label for="sponsorclubname1">Sponsor club name 1:</label></span>
            <span class="t_formColumn2"><input  type="text" id="cosponsorcontact" name="cosponsorcontact"  placeholder="Name" title="Co-sponsor contact" /></span>
            <span class="t_formColumn3"><input  type="text" id="cosponsoremail"  name="cosponsoremail"     placeholder="Email" title="Co-sponsor email" /></span>
            <span class="t_formColumn4"><input  type="text" id="cosponsorphone"  name="cosponsorphone"     placeholder="Phone" title="Co-sponsor phone" /></span>
      </div>
       <div class="clear"></div>
        </div>

   <div class="clear"></div>
        <p><span class="hyperlink">+ cosponsor</span></p>   

    </form>
<!-- Start Template to Clone -->
<span style="display:none">
        <div id="cosponsorsTemplate">
            <span class="t_formColumn1"><label for="sponsorclubname1">Sponsor club name</label></span>
            <span class="t_formColumn2"><input  type="text" id="cosponsorcontact" name="cosponsorcontact"  placeholder="Name" title="Co-sponsor contact" /></span>
            <span class="t_formColumn3"><input  type="text" id="cosponsoremail"  name="cosponsoremail"     placeholder="Email" title="Co-sponsor email" /></span>
            <span class="t_formColumn4"><input  type="text" id="cosponsorphone"  name="cosponsorphone"     placeholder="Phone" title="Co-sponsor phone" /></span>
      </div>
</span>    
<!-- End Template to Clone -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: One might ask why you even need id values at all if they are dynamically generated?

Comment: You don't have to give them unique names. All possible values will be submitted to the `action=` script in order. If you're processing with PHP on the server, append `[]` to your input's `name` (`name="cosponsoremail[]"`) and it will automatically be parsed into an ordered array.

Comment: my guess is div:last doesn't select what you think it does. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/pdHCc/4/ though i'd suggest getting rid of the id's all together so that you don't need to make them unique, then leave the names alone.

Comment: When you copy your template your DOM has two elements with same ID and  then using copy variable will not work. You should give your template a separate ID that you copy and create your first visible element from that template as well. I usually keep a hidden template and update its ID for next one and just copy that across and update hidden template everytime.

Comment: see my sample here with above technique http://jsbin.com/utoyej/85/edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector `$('#myForm div:last')` is grabbing a `<div class="clear"></div>`  why not just use the `copy` object that you already have to reference the new div?

Example - http://jsfiddle.net/pdHCc/6/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/pdHCc/5/

The selector being used was wrong

```
$('#myForm div:last') => $('#' + cosponsorDivId)
```